# Download SQL Server Profiler for SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, profiler, sql-server-express

How can I profile a SQL Server 2008 database to see code that's being executed on a particular database?  I remember using the SQL Server profiler, but I don't see it in SQL Server Management Studio after downloading SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.  Where can I download that tool and install it?  Do I need the full version of SQL Server 2008 in order to see this option?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[SQL Profiler does not come with SQL Server Express 2008 R2*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  You can get it with the installation media for Datacenter, Enterprise, Standard, Web, Developer, or Workgroup licenses.

If you have the installation media, you can get Profiler that way.  Otherwise, [Developer Edition is available for $50](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/en_US/pd/ThemeID.27509700/SQL-Server-2008-R2-Developer-Edition/productID.221634300).

There are some other tools available, and you could even create your own server-side traces ([for example](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10400.the-server-side-trace-what-why-and-how.aspx)) without Profiler.  Then, use a tool like [Qure Workload Analyzer](http://www.dbsophic.com/qure-analyzer.html) to review the trace files.  With 2008 R2, you could in addition use Extended Events to track activity.  The advantage is that both of these are less of a performance hit than running Profiler would be.

If you're looking at a point-in-time solution and can install procedures, [Adam Machanic's sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com) could be something to look into.

* Profiler [is available in SQL Server 2012 Express Edition SP1 onward](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2013/01/30/express-edition-revisited-focus-on-ssms.aspx). You need to select SSMS (Complete) in the installation options.

Comment: As of March 2016 Sql Server **DEVELOPER EDITION IS NOW FREE**. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/03/31/microsoft-sql-server-developer-edition-is-now-free/ Woohoo

Answer (score 8):

Even though SQL Profiler does not come with SQL Server Express, you can still create server-side traces using T-SQL.

Check out [`sp_trace_create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190362.aspx) and [`sp_trace_setevent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186265.aspx). The page for `sp_trace_setevent` also has a list of traceable event numbers.

Finally, if you need a place to get started, [this link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1035/sql-server-performance-statistics-using-a-server-side-trace/) may serve as a good jumping-off point.

Answer (score 7):

There is a free, open source tool called ExpressProfiler - https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/
Very convenient tool. In addition to SQL Express databases, it even supports a localDB.

Answer (score 3):

It's not included with Express Edition, but the other (non-free) editions have it, including Developer Edition, which is about $60 (USD) list. You may run into some sticky licensing situations, however, which I can't address with authority.

Answer (score 1):

If looking for a UI that will get traces in real-time, the ExpressProfiler is good.  But it's a bit simple, and not very configurable.

This is a nice alternative, very configurable and I use use it all the time now.  It's called Sql ExpressTRace and this link is to an article that lets you download the compiled UI and the code too: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/784905/Real-time-Tracing-With-SQL-Server-Express